# How to put up a very small barrier on concrete to stop water running past it

Tags: concrete, flooding

I have a concrete driveway that leads to the garage, with a very slight slope towards the garage.

When it really rains hard, the water comes down into the garage.

I don't want a very high barrier, just about an inch I guess would do.

What is the best way to do this please?

I will explore both good answers but cannot rebuild the driveway whilst I do have an appreciation for water and what it can do. This little wall will actually divert water from the garage wall to a channel that runs away from the property.

Comment: Instead of a raised barrier, how about a shallow trench to divert the water to one side?

Comment: Concrete speed hump across driveway opening should work,thanks for tip.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/97942)

Answer (score 6):

Glue-down garage door seal (sometimes called threshold seal) sounds like what you want. A rubber bump.

Comment: Thanks. The regular garage door has been replaced by a wall panel with a norm size door in it and the water can seep between theconcrete and timber that holds the frame. Whilst you are right if it was just a doorway, I am thinking of stopping and redirecting the water about 2 meters out from the door and panel. This way I would need like a tiny wall. Maybe there is a rubber thing that I could stick there ? oz

Comment: Same thing, just applied in front of the garage instead of under the door (since there isn't a door.)

Comment: apply it at an angle or a V patern so the water runs to the side instead of pooling in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I made a 1" high, 3" wide concrete bump using some angled wood strips to hold it until set. The two strips were joined using small cross-bracing pieces of wood screwed from above. The strips were something like a 6 or 7 foot length of 2x1" wood at about 45 degrees to the ground. I made the concrete bump in sections that length. I think I used a sack of ready-mixed concrete to which I just added water.

It worked well because I have a surface drain one foot in front of the bump and I just needed to hold the water a little from rushing past the drain into my garage. It was only ever a problem when there was sudden heavy rain.

Whether this will work for you depends on your exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do what I did, speed bump across the opening 1",2" or 3" avil.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if an old car tire could be cut into strips about 2" wide with a sawsall and dispose of the sidewall completely.
This would form 2" rings, you could probably get at least 3 per tire. (Depending on the width of the tire).
Then cut the rings open and lay out the 2" wide strips on the desired area and screw them into the existing pavement with concrete screws from local Ace hardware.
I imagine you would yield 4' long strips, (depending on the size of the tire of course). So, probably 10 - 12 ft. of strip per tire.
If it works it would be a great ECO solution.  Good Luck!

Comment: Good idea untill you try cutting a tire the steel cords are really tough and the rubber smoke. Just glad I did not catch the one on fire I tried to cut.

Answer (score -2):

I was looking up how to stop floods then voila!! It came to me floodwater safety barriers!!!!!

Comment: Do you mean sandbags?

Comment: The OP is asking for a 1" high barrier, I haven't seen any floodwater safety barrier that is that small and which could be installed permanently in a driveway allowing cars to drive across it.

Answer (score -2):

found this on amazon. might suite your needs
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00Y180CZ0/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=2SCND7XBHW0LG&coliid=I1RN33C491QTH0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y180CZ0)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/64148/2196 which doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score -3):

My advice is never, and I mean NEVER fool around with water. Don’t just put some small barrier, because then water will stop at the barrier and from there God knows where will it go from there. You can cause much bigger damage than it is now. I know that you not going to like what I'm about to say but you really should rebuild entire driveway properly.

Comment: A proper drain to move the water to a safe location, might be a bit easier than building a new driveway.

Comment: @Tester101 I must admit that I haven't considered this option and generally it is a good idea. But because of my professional experience (I've seen what water can do in extreme situations) I would always go for proper slope. Drain could be corked; his capacity could be insufficient in case of extreme rain etc. But if properly sloped driveway is not option this is second best solution for sure.